# Codeignater, data all null in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, postman

There is a problem I am facing...when performing POST from my controller, I want to pass JSON and not sure how to convert it to array Tried to use

```
json_decode($array, true);
JSON example: 
[
 { "example": 1,
    "user": 0
 },
 { "example": 2,
    "user": 1
 }
]
```

Postman I use to initiate POST from gives me back: "status": "Malformed UTF-8 characters". What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: your encoded is possibly incorrect
and make sure when you are trying to post a json type, the `content-type` header should be `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the character set you're sending might not be in the right encoding for the API to recieve. Try converting the character encoding with `mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')` before parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with incorrectly encoding utf characters.

Try returning the response as below.

```
return utf8_encode($data);
```

Or try character encoding as follows.

```
mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```